# Convert a LAN port to WAN port

Tags: router, wifi, d-link

I have D-Link DIR-600M N-Modem. A day ago the WAN port got damaged due to lightning but the other ports still work. I can connect to the modem but the WAN port does not respond.

Is there any way I can configure one of the LAN port out of the 4 switch ports to work as WAN port?

*My I.P provider provides a static IP address. I also use the modem as a WiFi hotspot.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you can't**

The WAN port on that device is a routed port.  It can have a different network address than your LAN network address and the LAN traffic would be routed through the WAN port to get to your ISP.

Unfortunately there are no Layer 3 ports on your switch side of the router.

You asked.

> Is there any way I can configure one of the LAN port out of the 4 ports to work as WAN port?

No, there is not a way to configure one of your LAN switch port as a WAN port for your device.